# get rgb values from tkinter color names

Tags: python, tkinter, rgb, color-mapping

I need a mapping between every tkinter "color name" and "color value(in rgb e.g.)".
It could be a one-by-one corresponding list or a function to convert those.

There are functions like matplotlib's hex2color or to_rgba but they don't support all tkinter color names as some of them are too special to the module(like "ghost white"); and I wonder of course there must be one specific to tkinter itself as its developers has needed that to implement the module.

Comment: For the record: If you just want to know that RGB of a colour, you can look it up in the [tcl docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/colors.htm). You can make that into a python dictionary and have a function that looks it up.

Comment: Wow, Thanks. That's exactly what I needed.
By the way, is it a way to export that neatly so that I can give it to Python.
For now I copied and pasted it and have to write a small code to make it clean and then give it Python...

Comment: I just copied and pasted it in python and converted it into a dictionary. It's just string manipulation to convert it from a string to a `dict`

Answer (score 5):

Use the `winfo_rgb` method. If you pass it yellow, it will return the rgb value (16 bit) which you can then just divide by 256 to get the approx 8 bit value.

```
root.winfo_rgb('yellow')
```

returns
(65535, 65535, 0)

```
root.winfo_rgb('ghostwhite')
```

returns
(63736, 63736, 65535)

A oneliner to get the 8bit RGB values as a tuple is

```
rgb = tuple((c//256 for c in root.winfo_rgb('ghostwhite')))
```